# Spring Boot - Download zip file using REST

Tags: angular, spring-boot, rest

I have a front-end profile, but I'm currently working with a platform that requires using Spring Boot to connect to a back-end service.

The service should exclusively download the local zip file that is generated on the back-end, when I run it from Postman it works fine and downloads the file, but when I try to play it from an Angular app the service returns the following error:

```
Request Metho: POST
Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed
```

In some readjustment that he did, instead of a 405 he gave me a:

```
The media type is not supported HTTP 415
```

Using Angular, when I hit the download button from the web page, this is the call I make in the angular component:

```
  this.downloadService.downloadFile(fileName, body).subscribe(response => {
    console.log("response:", response);
  }, error  => {
    console.log("error:", error);
  });
```

Using Angular, this is the service (the "body" variable is an array of objects needed by the Rest service to generate the download Zip file):

```
downloadFile(fileName: string, body?: any): Observable<any> {
    let headerContentType = [{ "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream" }];
    return this.service.post<any>("/download", body).pipe();
}
```

This is the code in Sprint Boot (I think the error is in this code, but I don't know what I am missing or what is left over):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/download")
@Tag(name = "download-files", description = "Descarga de archivos")
public class DownloadFilesController {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DownloadFilesController.class);
    @Value("${business.service.resource.download}")
    String businessResourceRegulatorUnit;
    @Autowired
    BusinessProxyService<BusinessSolutionRequest<Void>, Void> businessProxyServiceFile;

    @Operation(summary = "Download files connection to BS")
    @PostMapping(consumes = { "application/octet-stream" })
    @SecurePublic()
    public ResponseEntity<Void> downloadFiles(HttpServletResponse downloadResponse) {
        logger.info("Invoke download files business service.");
        ConnectionDetails connectionDetails = BusinessSolutionRequest.withUri(businessResourceRegulatorUnit).httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST).responseClass(Void.class).build();
        BusinessSolutionRequest<InputStreamResource> businessSolutionRequest = new BusinessSolutionRequest<>();
        businessProxyServiceFile.invoke(businessSolutionRequest, connectionDetails, response -> {
            FileCopyUtils.copy(response.getBody(), downloadResponse.getOutputStream());
            return null;
        });
        return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).build();
    }
}
```

NOTE: The path uri is correct.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It is producing "application/octet-stream" not consuming it because you are downloading file without giving any input in body or request param.

So please do these changes are try again.

1. In backend change attribute name **consumes** to **produces**

```
 @PostMapping(produces = { "application/octet-stream" })
```

2. In frontend use **Accept** header.

```
downloadFile(fileName: string, body?: any): Observable<any> {
    let headerContentType = [{ "Accept": "application/octet-stream" }];
    return this.service.post<any>("/download", body).pipe();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the service no longer returns a 405 or 415, now it is a 500, which is already progress, now I will continue investigating.